# php select не отображать пустые поля

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет! Помогите сделать запрос чтобы не отображались пустые ячейки в столбце name.
То есть нужно чтобы выводились все записи ds = 1 только где поле name заполнено.

$resultat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `invlist` WHERE `ds` = '1' GROUP BY name;",$db);

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
$resultat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM invlist WHERE ds = '1' AND name <> '' AND name IS NOT NULL GROUP BY name;", $db);
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно )))